# SignalR works partially on Remote Server IIS 7.5. Works fine in VS 2012. MVC4

Tags: iis-7.5, signalr, windows-server-2008-r2

There are similar questions but mine is a peculiar case. My signalr application works only partially on IIS 7.5

My SignalR implementation is working only partially.

I'm using SignalR 1.3, .Net Framework 4.0. MVC4
and IIS 7.5 on Wondows 2008r2

The following lines of code do execute. I get an alert and I'm able to send a message to all the clients.

```
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
alert("hi signalr started")
 $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                    chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                    $('#message').val('').focus();
                });
});
```

But

```
public override Task OnConnected()
    {
       Clients.Caller.getClientName();

       return base.OnConnected();
    }
```

This method is failing to call client method getClientName().

```
chat.client.getClientName = function () {
                //a method that the onConnect method calls to get the user's name
                alert("hi");

            };
```

I don't get an alert in this case.

Everything is working fine if I run it on VS 2012.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Did you add support for extensionless URLs?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980368

Also note you will need to update your web server to IIS 8.0 to get WebSockets support.

For further details, see the Supported Platforms doc"

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/supported-platforms

Comment: I did. I see a very strange behavior. OnConnected method is getting called. Also I could debug and see that connectionID is accessible in OnConnected() method. I tried with "Clients.Client(ConnectionID)..." but is still failing call the the client method in my view.            I am able to call Client methods from OnDisconnected() though. I skipped calling client method from OnConnected() to fix my issue but I'm still not sure what was going wrong when its on IIS7.5 . May be IIS 8 will work.